# SwiftUI and VIP Clean: possible leak and how to fix?

Tags: swiftui

First of all I am quite new to SwiftUI so bear with me if something is done way too wrong.

I am trying to introduce SwiftUI in our codebase while at the same time sticking to the VIP Clean architecture that we use throughout the app. Everything has been smooth enough - regardless the fact that View now is a struct instead of a class and some changes are needed when setting the module.

However there is a possible leak to the whole flow, and some types are not deallocated when the View disappears.

[image]

[image]

My code is - briefly - the following

Setting up the module:

```swift
class Module {
    func createView() -> some View {
        let interactor = Interactor()
        let presenter = Presenter()
        let view = MenuView(viewModel: MenuViewModel(), interactor: interactor)

        interactor.presenter = presenter
        presenter.view = view

        return view
    }
}
```

View types

```swift
struct MenuOption: Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    let title: String
    let isSelected: Bool
}

struct MenuSection: Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    let items: [MenuOption]
}

class MenuViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var sections: [MenuSection] = []
}
```

View

```swift
struct MenuView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel: MenuViewModel
    let interactor: InteractorProtocol

    var body: some View {
        Menu {
            ForEach(viewModel.sections.indices, id: \.self) { sectionIndex in
                let section = viewModel.sections[sectionIndex]
                Section {
                    ForEach(section.items.indices, id: \.self) { itemIndex in
                        let item = section.items[itemIndex]
                        Button { [weak interactor] in
                            interactor?.didSelect(index: itemIndex, section: sectionIndex)
                        } label: {
                            Label(item.title, systemImage: item.isSelected ? "checkmark" : "")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        label: {
            Image(systemName: "name")
        }
        .menuOrder(.fixed)
        .onAppear {  [weak interactor] in interactor?.configure() }
    }
}

extension MenuView: MenuViewProtocol {
    func update(sections: [MenuSection]) {
        self.viewModel.sections = sections
    }
}
```

So, the flow is basically that `onAppear` the view calls the interactor which in its turn goes through presenter -> view and updates the view with the `func update(sections: [MenuSection])` method.

Is something tricky when using ObservedObject which doesn't get deallocated or maybe every ObservedObject that you instantiate is supposed to stay alive throughout app runtime?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Struct instead of class is not the only difference. The View struct is now the view model. SwiftUI diffs the structs and uses the difference to create/update/remove UIView objects automatically. So you should remove your view model object and use the View with lets for read only `@Binding var` for write access. `body` is called when the properties change from the last time the View was init.